# Power Bi - Direct Query parameters applied only after button click

Tags: parameter-passing, powerbi-desktop

I have a power bi (desktop) report that has a few parameters. The report uses views (direct query) and passes these parameters to the view on the where clause dynamically. I saw a YouTube video recently but cannot locate it where they showed how to add a button (or some control) that when selected the parameters are applied to the direct query. This sql query only executes once all the parameters have been selected rather multiple times.

Can someone show me how to achieve this?

Comment: Are you talking about [query reduction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-directquery-about#report-design-guidance)?

Comment: Yes. I found the option to set so now this works.